# jQuery parent() method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't the `parent()` method in Jquery work in the following case?

```
$('.class')[0].parent();
```

The error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

but if I use:

```
$('.class').parent();
```

it works and give me all the parents of all elements with class `class`. I know how make it in jQuery but the question is why the browser interprets it like a JavaScript code and not like a jQuery code when I use `[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$('.class')[0]` is accessing the DOM element within the [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

[Native DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) don't have jQuery methods, which is *why* you are receiving an error.

You could use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access it by its index:

```
$('.class').eq(0).parent();
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the DOM element `$('.class')[0]` with `$()` to convert it to a jQuery object:

```
$($('.class')[0]).parent();
```

(Use the `.eq()` method instead though.)

Answer (score 1):

The `.parent()` method works fine for jQuery objects. Your problem is that you're trying to use it with something that isn't a jQuery object.

When you fetch elements from a jQuery object with `[ ]` notation, you get raw DOM element node references. Those don't have a `parent()` method.

You can use the `.eq()` jQuery method to limit the set of elements involved to the first one matched, or just add `:first` to the selector:

```
$('.class:first').parent();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($('.class').first().parent().html());

//or

console.log($('.class').eq(0).parent().html());
console.log($('.class').eq(1).parent().html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="class">
    1
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="class">
    2
    </div>
  </div>
```